# Delay method to add class to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a sort of "slider". I have 9 items in a line within a single div called `#slider`.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5Pk3/2/)

`slider` is 1860px wide, but only 620px of it is shown at a time (as the parent is `overflow:hidden`)

I want to shift the position of `slider` along, to reveal another 3 of my items at a time, after a delay of about 6 seconds. It should then shift along again after another 6 seconds, then revert back.

So I have created two classes:

```
.slideLeft620{
    left:-620px;
}

.slideLeft1240{
    left:-1240px;
}
```

Animating between the standard (without this `left` value) I would hope would allow the contents to appear to "slide".

So I want to:

1. After 6 seconds, add class `slideLeft620` to `slider`
2. After another 6 seconds, remove `slideLeft620` and add `slideLeft1240` to `slider`
3. After another 6 seconds, remove class `slideLeft1240`

This is what I tried to get started (just doing number 1. at the moment) but I can't get it working.

```
$("#slider").addClass("slideLeft620").delay(100);
```

(I'm aware 100 is a random value at the mo).

Any idea why this won't work? The delay should call the .addClass after a few moments?

Edit: suggestion to call .delay first doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#slider").delay(100).addClass("slideLeft620");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to call delay before addClass. `$("#slider").delay(6000).addClass("slideLeft620").delay(6000).removeClass("slideLeft620").addClass("slideLeft1240");`

Comment: @A1rPun thanks for your suggestion, have tried this but doesn't work? See OP for changes.

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off with css3 animation - check out [this post](http://css-tricks.com/css-animation-tricks/)

Comment: This has been done a thousand ways and jQuery.delay() wont be your only delay. Just pick a carousel like look at  http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delay()` only works on jQuery methods that adds to the FX queue, and that's basically just animation methods, it does not work for `addClass`, you could use a timeOut instead

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#slider").addClass("slideLeft620");
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks, have added this but does not seem to add the class still: http://jsfiddle.net/K5Pk3/5/

Comment: I believe it would work if you include jQuery UI... it can animate classes ([addClass](http://jqueryui.com/addClass/))

Comment: I would expect the code above to result in the class being added to slider.

Comment: Thanks, have added jQuery UI to the fiddle and it works. Any idea how to add a slide animation to the above? And how to remove the class after a further 6 and swap with the other class as above?

Comment: ^ If you just add jQuery to the fiddle, it adds the class just fine. Note that 100 milliseconds is 0.1 seconds, so it won't be very noticeable.

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now however I have realised I need this to repeat/cycle through and start from the beginning. So instead of after 6 seconds it should be "every 6 seconds" or "every 12 seconds" or "every 18 seconds". I have updated JSFiddle and it works but no cycle nor animation http://jsfiddle.net/K5Pk3/9/

Comment: Thanks, this works. Any idea on animation? I tried adding a time to the .addClass to give the transition some time but it still doesn't slide/fade etc

Comment: Adding a class doesn't generally animate anything, it just adds the class. If you want animation use jQuery animate() or CSS animations. In some cases jQuery UI can animate class changes, but it adds a lot of overhead as well.